# What's the name of this connector and where can I find it?

Tags: connector

This is from a motorized kayak - supposed to be waterproof but got damaged and I can't open it or find a replacement for it.
Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My Identiconn utility identifies it as an [XS connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=xs_circular_conn).

If you tell us the following info, we can identify the exact one.

1. The inner diameter of the outer ring
2. Whether the outer ring can turn just a partial turn (self-latching) or turns unimpeded (threaded)

[image: XS plug]

{[AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/2251832727420632.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt)}